# The new user page layout requires some work

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-interface, users-page

I quite like the *idea* of the new [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users), but the design is horrible. It looks incredibly messy. Understandably it's hard to get dynamic content perfect in every scenario, but the page just looks like it can be improved.

I think that no text should ever be under the profile image as that's a major contribution to the messy-esque look. Also, is there really a need to repeat *week*, *quarter*, etc after every rep score? I already know it's the weekly rep as that's the highlighted option.

This is what it looks like *at the time of writing*:

[image]

Here's a quick idea for what I think will probably look better (made in *Paint*):

[image: BetterUserLayout]

Comment: I would also like the old top-down sorting back instead of the new left-right one, i.e. 1st on the top left and 2nd below of 1st, not to the right.

Comment: I'm missing seeing people's badge-count in the user summary. It's an interesting second view into someone's participation in the site.

Comment: @matt that implies we would show badges earned just during the specified interval, which is rather painful given the SO dataset

Answer (score 6):

Here's my attempt (in [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/)).  A 2-column layout loosely based on the [stackexchange.com leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow).

- Rank number gives context (otherwise it's not clear how the columns work), and opens the possibility of showing the current user at the top (ala [stackexchange.com leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow))
- Second column shows normal user info in a 3-line user card, but could be 2-line.  Badge count could be swapped for location, or moved to 2nd line and location on the 3rd (might be too busy, though)
- Third column is their rep in this period (and the largest number on the page, for emphasis)
- Extra room for longer tags in the last column

[image]

Comment: +1 for putting the tags in boxes.

Answer (score 2):

I think we have enough room, even with the margin, for 2 lines of tags so we can fit 3 tags in there.

Originally we were using tag styling which was much more visually jarring and took more space, so that's why we had them underneath.

Now that the tags are plain vanilla unstyled links this left margin is possible, so I made that change.

Comment: I still don't like the way that the location and the tags seem to merge together.

Comment: @gen ah, I just noticed that you changed the order of the items. I will do that too.

Comment: Are these changes going to be applied to other SE sites too, or should I post a separate request?

Comment: @tsu in general, it is rare for a feature *not* to go to every site -- so you can safely assume this will always be the case, features are network-wide.